# how to calculate time from previously saved time to current time

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2015

I have saved time in database. Now I Select that time from database and I want to calculate how many minutes elapsed from that time to current time

This is my c# code

```
TimeSpan ts=DateTime.Now.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(reader1["cur_tim‌​e"].ToString())); 
MessageBox.Show(ts.TotalMinutes.ToString());
```

Comment: subtract the first one from the second one?

Comment: it is not working correctly.. i have tried

Comment: show your code...

Comment: can you please share your code?

Comment: select (CURTIME()-cur_time) from table

Comment: what do you mean by not working correctly? does it return an unexpected result, or does it give you an error?

Comment: sorry that was my error in the logic so thats why there were unexpected results. as some other help me and i correct it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate like this-

```
TimeSpan ts = DateTime.Now.Subtract(dbDateTimeCOlumn);
Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalMinutes);
```

Comment: TimeSpan ts=DateTime.Now.Subtract(Convert.ToDateTime(reader1["cur_time"].ToString()));
                MessageBox.Show(ts.TotalMinutes.ToString());
i tried this but not working

Comment: Do you get any error? What is the value of `reader1["cur_tim‌​e"]`?

Comment: the value is time which i have saved in database

Comment: But what is that value? Any error you get when you execute above line?

Comment: thank you very much. that was my error in code. the value is updating database by current time so subtracting from current time is not giving right answer. I did not see in database when i see, i correct it.

Answer (score 1):

to get the difference in time in sql use the DATEDIFF function:

```
DATEDIFF(mi, CurTime(), cur_time)
```

Comment: what is mi in your code??

Comment: minutes, read the help for DATEDIFF